# TypeError: userData.users.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get a simple `react-redux` app to work and I am running into a weird error that I can't figure out. I am trying to simply set my current user's name and handle the store.

`UserRole.js`
shows a TypeError: "*userData.users.map is not a function.*"

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchUsers } from '../../redux/actions/userActions'
// import { CButton } from '@coreui/react'

function UserRole({ userData, fetchUsers }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers()
    }, [])


    return userData.loading ? (
        <h2>Loading</h2>
    ) : userData.error ? (
        <h2>{userData.error}</h2>
    ) : (
        <>
            <div>
                <h2>Users List</h2>
                <div>
                    {userData && userData.users && userData.users.map((user) => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userData: state.user,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserRole)
```

`UserAction.js`

I have them as actions in the userActions.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { FETCH_USERS_REQUEST, FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS, FETCH_USERS_FAILURE } from './userTypes'

export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersRequest())
        axios
            .post(https://localhost:3000)
            .then((response) => {
                // response.data is the users
                const users = response.data
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // error.message is the error message
                dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error.message))
            })
    }
}

export const fetchUsersRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
    }
}

export const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: users,
    }
}

export const fetchUsersFailure = (error) => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
        payload: error,
    }
}
```

And in the reducer in `UserReducer.js`

```
import { FETCH_USERS_REQUEST, FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS, FETCH_USERS_FAILURE } from '../actions/userTypes'

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
    error: '',
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                users: action.payload,
                error: '',
            }
        case FETCH_USERS_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                users: [],
                error: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

`store.js`

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './redux/reducers/rootReducer'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger, thunk))
)

export default store
```

What do I have incorrect?

Comment: Have you validated the contents of `userData` and `userData.users`?

Comment: `users` is initially an array, so if it's later not mappable then it would seem you've mutated the state invariant to be something other than an array. Please share what the `user` payload value is that you are dispatching to the store.

Comment: I was going to second what Capt 171 said. My first guess is that you may be using the MAP function to iterate over an object, not an array. 

Can you check for us if userData.users is an array?